# Time data with irregular intervals

Tags: python, django, highcharts

In django-chartit I made a chart that has datetime on X-axis, but it does not scale properly. The problem is the distance (on x-axis) between dots will be always the same, regardless if it was 2 days between the last 2 inputs of new data or 10 minutes. The problem in Highcharts can be solved as shown in [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time). Is it possible to implement this in django-chartit?

I suppose these lines make the trick, but I do not know how to properly define them in django-chartit.

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
```

EDIT: This question has been answered by Kacper Madej.

Another question I have (so I don't open new thread); is it possible to rotate labels on axis (for 90° or any other amount really) making it easier to read?

Comment: To rotate labels set rotation for them - [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.rotation) - [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/af6vpr52/)

Comment: Thanks, it did work. I guess I should check django-chartit library to see which options from highcharts are included.